# Change XML shape color while app is running

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to change rectangle (drawn in xml) color in Java code while app is running?

My rectangle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp" />

    <solid android:color="#006600" />
</shape>
```

Drawn in main.xml by:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

I've tried this way:

```
   GradientDrawable sd;
    View viewrectangle;
    viewrectangle = (View) findViewById(R.id.myRectangleView);
    sd = (GradientDrawable) viewrectangle.getBackground();
    sd.setColor(0xffffff00);
    sd.invalidateSelf();
```

It only works when I put it inside OnCreate method.

I want to change rect color by a button, so I put this code inside button's onClick() method. But when I click button while app is running color doesn't change. Any suggestions?

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, or helped you solve it, you should click the check mark next to that answer to mark it as the accepted answer and give the author credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Used this code and it worked, alternatively consider redrawing the viewrectangle using viewrectangle.invalidate(), but it shouldn't be nescarry:

```
View viewrectangle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    viewrectangle = (View) findViewById(R.id.myRectangleView);

}

public void doClick(View v) {
    GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) viewrectangle.getBackground();
    sd.setColor(0xffffff00);
    sd.invalidateSelf();
}
```

In this example the "doClick()" method is set in the main.xml:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="doClick"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in a separate method, and that method you can call from onClick of button..

Answer (score 0):

You could try a color filter.  I've used it before to change the color of buttons (note that they started out as standard gray), if you start with another color it could be a very different outcome.  Anyway, an example of how I did it:

Import the PorterDuff graphics stuff:

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
```

In the class define the item you want to color filter and set the filter:

```
Button atdButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attendbutton);

    if (atdState[position].equals("P")) {
        atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,  // Set filter to green
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else if (atdState[position].equals("T")) {
        atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFF00,  // Set filter to yellow
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else if (atdState[position].equals("E")) {
        atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF6600,  // Set filter to orange
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else if (atdState[position].equals("U")) {
        atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,  // Set filter to red
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else {
        atdButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
    }
```